# AWS - Firewall Manager - WAF Rules How to block requests from IP address (No Host name)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, firewall

I am using AWS Firewall manager for my website, with Web-ACL to deny DOS attacks and Hacking requests.

However, I still get below requests coming through to my webserver, from Firewall Configuration (Missing my waf-rules) In below example lets assume that 3.6.8.8 is my web server IP address.

```
3.6.8.8/ecp/Current/exporttool/microsoft.exchange.ediscovery.exporttool.application
3.6.8.8/actuator/health
3.6.8.8/remote/fgt_lang?lang=/../../../..//////////dev/cmdb/sslvpn_websession
```

In real legitimate case, none of my acceptable requests should not be calling via direct IP like 3.6.8.8, for example, all my website requests are like below

```
https://*.example.com/*
```

I wonder how can I block the above requests that are pretending to be originating from my Ip address 3.6.8.8 with WAF rule?

Comment: honestly, i did not get your question but if it is about blocking a specific IP in WAF then you can create a IP set in WAF with the IP 3.6.8.8. Then create a IP rule inside your web acl. Select the created IP set and set the action to block so that any requests coming from this IP will be blocked. Let me know if you were looking for something else.

Comment: @node_saini this not simple as adding ip to blocklist, its about blocking IP based requests being severred, all requests should come from proper hostname not a IP address.

Comment: hostname is just a user friendly names for us. It is the IP which does all the work. You cannot block a domain by its name. Do you want to block certain paths? Also, no one can pretend to be originating from your IP as IPs are unique. May be i am not able to understand your problem. Can you give more clarity on your requirement? May be try editing your question to make it more simple.

Comment: If you want requests to come from proper hostnames not an IP address then you need to buy a domain for that. You could use Route53 in AWS or any third party will also work.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your rule statement in your WAF web ACL to **Inspect** the **Header** and set your **Header field name** to **Host** and finally specify a **Match Type** to a regex pattern.

With this configuration you can create a regex that checks if the Host is an IP address. If it is, block the request.

Hope this helped!

Comment: this didnt work, as some request dont have host header set, i am looking to detect if its IP address

Comment: Having a host header is required for http requests. How are you sending requests without one? The host defines the endpoint of your URI. For example: if host: 3.6.8.8 then URI: http://3.6.8.8, and if host: example.com then URI: http://example.com.

Comment: Request dont have a hostname, Clients that generate HTTP/2 requests directly SHOULD use the ":authority" pseudo-header field instead of the Host header field. An intermediary that converts an HTTP/2 request to HTTP/1.1 MUST create a Host header field if one is not present in a request by copying the value of the ":authority" pseudo-header field

Comment: Have you tried using the the pseudo-header ":authority" to validate the hostname?

Answer (score 1):

we have the exact same problem.  Even to the point where the URLs that are being probed are Exchange related (just like one of your examples above).

The short answer is that there is NO AWS Firewall rule that will block these requests because by using your Web Server's IP address in the URL, they are circumnavigating the AWS firewall and talking directly with your web server.

*.example.com will resolve to the AWS firewall device but 3.6.8.8 goes directly to your web server.

What we have seen over the years is that bad actors compile lists of sites to probe and store both the host name AND the IP address so they can get around firewalls once they are put in place. (usually at a later date, after the site is up and running).

So, the only real solution is to turn off HTTP/HTTPS access to your webserver from the outside world and only allow traffic from the AWS Load Balancer.  This can be done in the Security Group your EC2 Instance is tied to.

I hope that helps!